# magento disable cron job from database

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, cron, observers

Is it possible to disable or delete cron job from magento database .
Have added cron job , and accidentally I had added ***** , which executes the cron job every seconds and function adds data in database .

Due to which my ftp access has stopped .
I want to diable/delete it from phpmyadmin .
Please help

Comment: did you try to empty the cron table?

Comment: @OSdave won't the cron just repopulate the table though? Nikhil_K_R you sure have got yourself in a conundrum there, you need to get access to your server pronto.

Comment: @input yep, it will, but without access to source files there isn't much he can do.

Comment: @input OSdave : Have replaced the table name , so atleast the data won't be added in DB .

Comment: Did you manage to get access? You could steal some tricks from the darkside if you have a badly configured server. If MySQL has the `INTO OUTFILE` command available and a writeable directory you can upload a PHP Shell.

Comment: @input after changing the tablename , I don't know what happened but ftp started working .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do it in database table 'cron_schedule', without affect other magento functionality
ony you change 'status' to pending or success, durant job schedule, or set executed_at to further date